# How to get img alt and add in other line jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, alt

On page have many images with random `alt=""`
How to get current image alt on hover and add this alt here:

```
var img = jQuery('.bbc_img[alt="NEED_ADD_HERE"]').attr('src');
```

Sorry for my bad English language.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't get it wrong, you need the `alt` attribute on hover, so you can get the source image, right?

```
$('img').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    var alt = e.target.alt;
    $('#alt_hover').text(alt);


  var img = jQuery('.bbc_img[alt="'+alt+'"]').attr('src');
    $('#var_img').text(img);    
});
```

This will do the work, altought, you can obtain the same `src` directly:

```
$('img').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    var img = e.target.src;
    $('#var_img').text(img);    
});
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qtqbphj/10/)

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is the title attribute. The default behaviour (for the HTML title attribute) is to be displayed on hover over the HTML element.

The alt attribute on an image is required for valid HTML (and can be an empty string). It's purpose is allow screen readers to describe what the image is to blind users. In the case were the image is part of visual decoration (doesn't have any content), it can be empty (in which case the screen reader ignores it.

Comment: In my page can`t be empty. All images have alt. Example, for image site.com/myimage.jpg alt is a "myimage.jpg"